# Switch Screen/Activity By Swiping Android Java

Tags: java, android, listview, swipe, detection

I have an application with different screens/activity's. At the moment it works fine, but I've a previous and next button. I'll remove this button, and use a swipe move to "say" next of previous. I found a lot on the internet, Something about Action detection, But it doesn't work with my listview. When I swipe on a textview it works fine, but when I put the same code in my code with the listview, it doesn't detect anything anymore.

Can anybody help me?

In my own code I use a: ListAdapter, onItemClick and a public View getView to put some images and textviews in my listview.

The onTouchEvent what does not work with my listview.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
        // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            x1 = touchevent.getX();
            y1 = touchevent.getY();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            x2 = touchevent.getX();
            y2 = touchevent.getY();

            // if left to right sweep event on screen
            if (x1 < x2) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            // if right to left sweep event on screen
            if (x1 > x2) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            // if UP to Down sweep event on screen
            if (y1 < y2) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "UP to Down Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            // if Down to UP sweep event on screen
            if (y1 > y2) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Down to UP Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Update**

But everything I find is with different classes. In the examples, they use `fragment1.java`, `fragment2.java`, `fragment3.java`. But I have only my `main_activity.java` and these is running, and when I click my next button, it reloads the main activity, and shows other information And again and again. till my counter is on its max.

Comment: Please give us more details on the code you use.

Comment: I try to post some more details. Please let me know if you know enough now or not. Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you just use a ViewPager ?

Comment: honestly.. I don't know what a ViewPager is. Or be used for.. But I don't want tabs or something on top of my screen. Only the swipe to switch activity part..

Comment: It's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I go looking for the ViewPager! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think swipe should be from one fragment to another fragment not from activity to another avtivity..

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: you want swipe from one activity to another? you should change activity to fragment..

Comment: Yes, and I've one activity, that's my main activity. And my whole screen is a listview.. I don't know if that matters?! Thanks,

Comment: You can add listview to fragment..and add all this fragments wich you want to swipe in viewpager in MainActivity...

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ViewPager` instead of manually doing all the touch-calculations.
This will give you an overview over the `ViewPager` widget: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html